# Why the value of X is not incremented while assignment

Tags: c

I'm new to C language and I'm not entirely sure why on Line 4 when post-increment is done the value of `x` isn't  change what I mean is that

```
x = printf("%d",x++);
```

The value for `x` was `12` so the printf would print `12` and then `x` should be assigned `2` and while `++` was there `x` should be later changed with `2+1` and on line 6 pre-increment is done so output shouldn't be `124`.

Why x on line 4 isn't added?

Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int x = 12;

x = printf("%d", x++);

printf("%d", ++x);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just do one thing at a time. Will make your life a lot easier

Comment: Finally the return value of `printf` is assigned to `x`. `printf` reurns the number of characters writen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make yourself aware of **sequence point**. From [**this**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) *[emphasis mine]*:

> There is a sequence point after the evaluation of all function arguments and of the function designator, and **before the actual function call**.

From [**this**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec) *[emphasis mine]*:

> Increment operators initiate the side-effect of adding the value 1 of appropriate type to the operand. Decrement operators initiate the side-effect of subtracting the value 1 of appropriate type from the operand. As with any other side-effects, these operations **complete at or before the next sequence point**.

Looks at this statement:

```
x = printf("%d", x++);
```

The post increment operator increase the value of operand by `1` but **the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment operation**.
So, the value of `x` passed to `printf()` will be its original value which is `12` and due to sequence point, before calling `printf()` the value of `x` will be incremented by `1`. The return value of `printf()` will be assigned to `x` which overwrites the last value of `x` which is the incremented value due to post `++` operator. Hence, after this statement the value of `x` is `2`.

Comment: you saved my point of view about my memory, thank you (and UV of course) ^^

Answer (score 1):

> The value for x was 12 so the printf would print 12 and then x should be assigned 2 and while ++ was there x should be later changed with 2+1 and on line 6 pre-increment is done so output shouldn't be 124.

no, the assignment is done after all concerning `printf("%d", ++x);`, your code is equivalent to that :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int x = 12;

  int y = printf("%d", x++);

  x = y;

  printf("%d", ++x);

  return 0;
}
```

so `x = printf("%d", ++x);` does :

- *printf* writes 12
- then *x* is incremented to value 13
- then *x* is assigned to the result of *printf* valuing 2

then you execute `printf("%d", ++x);` while *x* values 2 before, so *x* is incremented before to be given in argument, so 3 is written

and the final print result is 123

PS. As said by @H.S.  in an other remark :There is a sequence point after the evaluation of all function arguments (x++ is an argument to printf()) and the pre/post increment/decrement operation complete at or before the next sequence point.

Answer (score -1):

This will work for you:

**++x** is prefix increment and the **x++** is postfix increment, and here is the difference on both of them:

The prefix increment returns the value of a variable after it has been incremented.

On the other hand, the more commonly used postfix increment returns the value of a variable before it has been incremented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 12;

    x = printf("%d", ++x);

    printf("%d", ++x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's not about the solution Its a question.